# Skin detection and removal in Emgucv

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am new to Image processing. In my application, I want detect and remove skin surrounding an eye.[image]

In the above image I want to extract the eye area (and eye brow) without skin.

First, I tried to perform skin detection before removing skin from the image. I used the `AdaptiveSkinDetector` method in emgu cv, Here is my code

```
AdaptiveSkinDetector a = new AdaptiveSkinDetector(1, AdaptiveSkinDetector.MorphingMethod.ERODE);
Image<Gray, Byte> skin = new Image<Gray, Byte>(ImageFramecolourrighteye.Width, ImageFramecolourrighteye.Height);

a.Process(ImageFramecolourrighteye, skin);

CvInvoke.cvShowImage("Skin detection", skin);
```

But the it is not detecting skin. Are there any errors in my code?
Is there any better way to perform skin detection? (using colors, perhaps?)
References / code sample would be useful.

Your help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to threshold the image to its binary form ?

Comment: Yes , used this code
Image<Gray, Byte> Binary_Image = eyebrow_img_crop.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(threshold_value), new Gray(255));

but not showing expected result

Answer (score 1):

Dont know about Emugcv but if your datast is consistent with your example, i think Local binary pattern can be used to detect the contour of the eye (without the skin).
You can find detailed explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) and implementations in [here](http://www.cse.oulu.fi/CMV/Research/LBP). Even Though the implementations are in matlab hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Skin is a very good example proven to be detected well by hue, detect using hue, and play with Saturation and Value until you reach the least nosiy ones, example below, there are many of them.
Hue detection will allow you to get skin regardless of its color or brightness.

http://bytefish.de/blog/opencv/skin_color_thresholding/